# What is the One-Definition Rule?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, definition, one-definition-rule

What exactly does the One-Definition Rule in C++ say?
The only trustworthy occurrence I can find is in *The C++ Programming Language, 3rd. ed., P. 9.2.3*. Is there any official definition of the rule except that?

Comment: Strongly related: [Does redefining a function from the standard library violate the one-definition rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41670800/514235)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The truth is in the standard (3.2 One definition rule) :

> No translation unit shall contain more
>   than one definition of any variable,
>   function, class type, enumeration type
>   or template.
>
> [...]
>
> Every program shall contain exactly
>   one definition of every non-inline
>   function or object **that is used in
>   that program**; no diagnostic required.
>   The definition can appear explicitly
>   in the program, it can be found in the
>   standard or a user-defined library, or
>   (when appropriate) it is implicitly
>   defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8). An
>   inline function shall be defined in
>   every translation unit in which it is
>   used.

Comment: Uh, it's a little more than that. It also concerns multiple translation units. And exceptions to rule (this makes it a bit difficult to talk about it!). Cheers,

Comment: Indeed, I would have to quote the whole page, so I went for the essential.

Answer (score 2):

The "One-Definition Rule" is the [[basic.def.odr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) subclause in the C++ standard.
This subclause contains a number of rules.
I will sumarize the most important ones.

Firstly, you cannot define something multiple times in the same file. If  you define something in multiple files, the definitions have to be identical. Furthermore, if you use something, a definition of it has to exist.

The sections below describe this in more detail.

### Only one definition per translation unit<sup>[1]</sup>

The first and most basic rule is [[basic.def.odr] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2):

> No [translation unit](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#def:translation_unit) shall contain more than one definition of any [definable item](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:item,definable).

For example, this means you cannot write the following:

```cpp
void foo() {} // OK
void foo() {} // error, more than one definition of foo in the same TU
```

In practice, the compiler would raise an error telling you "re-definition of foo".

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>A translation unit is basically one C++ source file. A header is not a translation unit, it is included into translation units.</sub>

### Only one definition per program, excluding templates and `inline`

Furthermore, [[basic.def.odr] p14](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14) regulates what happens across multiple translation units:

> For any definable item `D` with definitions in multiple translation units,
>
> - if `D` is a non-inline non-templated function or variable, or
> - if the definitions in different translation units do not satisfy the following requirements,
>
> the program is ill-formed; [...]

For example, this means that you cannot have two definitions `void foo() {}` in different source files. In practice, this would result in a linker error telling you "multiple defintions of foo".

Templates and inline functions are special, because they can be defined in multiple translation units as long as those definitions follow strict rules. Essentially, the definitions have to be equivalent. For example:

```cpp
// a.cpp
inline int bar() { return 0; }
// b.cpp
inline int bar() { return 0; } // OK
// c.cpp
inline int bar() { return 1; } // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

Note that this rule is very important for headers. `#include` essentially copies/pastes code into translation units, so defining anything in a header risks violating this rule.

### Everything that is odr-used<sup>[2]</sup> must be defined

Thirdly, it also defines so-called [odr-use](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use). Intuitively, [odr-use](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use) means that you use some construct in a way that its definition needs to exist.
For example:

```cpp
int foo(); // declaration, not a definition

using foo_type = decltype(foo); // decltype (unevaluated operand) is not odr-use.
int x = foo(); // calling a function is odr-use
```

To [odr-use](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use) something has consequences, stated in [[basic.def.odr] p11](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#11):

> Every program shall contain at least one definition of every function or variable that is [odr-used](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#def:odr-use) in that program outside of a [discarded statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#def:discarded_statement); no diagnostic required.

In practice, if you use a function and it isn't defined anywhere, you get a linker error telling you "no definition of foo".

---

<sup>[2]</sup> <sub>This term was originally just called "use"; C++11 introduced the term "odr-use" to make it more formal.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the 'one definition per program' clause and 'odr-use.'