# Emitting a signal from a static function with very specific conditions

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, signals, libcurl

So this is the minimal example code I'm attempting to get to work:

```
int GekkoFyre::CmnRoutines::curl_xferinfo(void *p, curl_off_t dltotal, curl_off_t dlnow,
                                          curl_off_t ultotal, curl_off_t ulnow)
{
    CurlStatistics stats;
    stats.ul_now = ulnow;
    stats.ul_total = ultotal;
    stats.dl_now = dlnow;
    stats.dl_total = dltotal;
    emit sendXferStats(stats);
}
```

And this is the header:

```
static int curl_xferinfo(void *p, curl_off_t dltotal, curl_off_t dlnow, curl_off_t ultotal,
                         curl_off_t ulnow);

signals:
    void sendXferStats(const CurlStatistics &stats);
```

And this is the reason why the function needs to be static:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_ptr, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, curl_xferinfo);
// Pass the struct pointer into the xferinfo function, but note that this is an
// alias to CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA
curl_easy_setopt(curl_ptr, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, &curl_struct.prog);
```

I know from various posts throughout StackOverflow that it is possible under certain conditions to emit a signal from a static function, such as this one: [Sending signal from static class method in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411153/sending-signal-from-static-class-method-in-qt)

What I want to know is, how do I do that in this instance? If it is at all possible? Thank you so much in advance, as any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: The answer you linked basically says you need to pass an object to the static function somehow. Either as a parameter or as a global/static variable.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to do it as a global variable, @krzaq. Would you mind posting an example?

Comment: Check out the second example in that post. `Foo::theFoo` is a static `Foo*` that is used to emit the signal.

Comment: @krzaq, thank you, but I'm not sure how and where to initialise the example `static Foo *theFoo;`. I'm getting errors when I apply it to my situation, so I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to initialize it before using it, I'd do it about the same time as initializing curl

Comment: But /how/ do I initialise it? I know it's something simple but for some reason, I'm not getting it. I really do apologise...

Comment: Assign a pointer to a `Foo` instance. Either have a `Foo` object with static/automatic lifetime and just say `Foo::theFoo = &fooObj` or just allocate it with `new` - but in this case I'd use `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` instead

Comment: Thank you so much, @krzaq, it's greatly appreciated :) And yes, a smart pointer would be a good idea.