# Initialisation of static class member. Why constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, static-members, constexpr

when I want to have a static pointer as a member of a class I need `constexpr`for the initialisation with `nullptr`.

```
class Application {
    private:
        constexpr static Application* app = nullptr;
}
```

Can someone explain me why I need to do that? I cannot find the exact reason why it`s necessary that the static variable has to exist at compile time.

Comment: how do you use `app` variable?

Comment: The pointer should work as a pointer to an instance of the Application class (respectively to an instance of a class which derives from the Application base class). 

I write a program with OpenGL and Freeglut and I need to "wrap" the c-interface of Freeglut (callback registration with class member function).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you're initialising it inside the class definition. That's only allowed for constant integral and enumeration types (always) and for `constexpr` data members (since C++11). Normally, you'd initialise it where you define it (outside the class), like this:

**Application.h**

```
class Application {
    private:
        static Application* app;
}
```

**Application.cpp**

```
Application* Application::app = nullptr;
```

Note that you need to provide the out-of-class definition even in the `constexpr` case, but it must not contain an initialiser then. Still, I believe the second case is what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. You wrote inside class initialisation is only allowed for constant ...-types. But it's possibly with non-constant ...-types too, isn't it?

Comment: @Meiner A `static` class data member can only be initialised inside a class if it is `constexpr` of literal type or it's `const`, not `volatile`, and is of integral or enumeration type.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Didn't realise that you only talk of the static in-class initialisation in the original comment.

Comment: @yau Can you clarify your edit suggestion? C++11 9.4.2/3 says that "The member shall still be defined
in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not
contain an *initializer.*"

Comment: In the case of a `constexpr static` member,  if it is not [odr-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) you do not need to provide an out-of-class declaration. From C++17, if a static data member is declared, it is implicitly `inline`  and it no longer needs to be declared out-of-class.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want it to be `constexpr` (and it's not an integer) then you need to initialise it outside of the class body:

```
class Application
{
private:
    static Application* app;
};

Application* Application::app = nullptr;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I don't have a preference for using constexpr or not. I'm more interested in the question why this special keyword is needed for in-class initialisation when it's not necessary for other forms of in-class initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you need to initialise a static member variable outside the class declaration, unless it is const. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547660/c-static-member-variable-and-its-initialization) explains it better than I could.

Comment: Very interesting link. I didn't have the ODR in mind. So the reason why constexpr works is the implicit const, right? I just realise, that I can't change a static variable later when initialised as a constexpr variable.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables do not need to "exist at compile time". But if you want to initialize a static variable inside the class, its value needs to be known at compile time.

However, I do not know the reason for this restriction.

Comment: I think the restriction has to do with the One-Definition-Rule. Look at Kindreads link, it goes more into detail.