# What is using T::T

Tags: c++, c++11

I read [this article](https://tristanbrindle.com/posts/beware-copies-initializer-list) but I don't understand the meaning of this part of the code:

```cpp
template <typename T> struct counted : T, private instance_counter<T>
{
  using T::T;
};
```

It must be something simple as "make visible all names from namespace" but I don't completely understand it.

Comment: Hint 1: `T` is the template argument and you inherited this class. Hint 2: `Classname::Classname` is the name of the constructor of a class.

Comment: In this context, using is used to inherit the base class's (`T`) constructors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347358/inheriting-constructors

Comment: There are no namespaces involved. `T` is a base class and in that case this is special syntax to inherit constructors of the base. (It has the different meaning than `using` has in other contexts.)

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [Questions about template and typename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884292/questions-about-template-and-typename/54884572#54884572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` is the base class.

`T::T` is/are the constructor(s) of the base class `T`.  A constructor has the same name as the class being constructed.

`using T::T;` brings the constructor(s) of the base class into the current scope, which is the derived class `counted`.

This line allows `counted` to be constructed using any constructor that `T` allows.

Answer (score 2):

> make visible all names from namespace

No, because `T` isn't a namespace. You can't derive from a namespace.

The [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/using) keyword has more than one meaning.

You're thinking of the *using directive* for namespaces, but the [*using declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) works for both namespace members (at namespace scope) and class members (inside a class). Since we already established `T` is not a namespace, this is obviously the second case.

Inside a class `using T::member` would normally just prevent base-class names being hidden by the derived class, but `T::T` means the base class constructor, which as a special case [inherits constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) from T.

```
template <typename T> struct counted : T
{
  using T::T; // now counted<T> can directly use any of T's constructors
};
```