# How to initialize a static member of a class conveniently?

Tags: c++, class, static, initialization

I have this class

```
class A
{
public:

static image* Table;
}
```

So i cant initialize `A::Table` in class and i can't do it in file with my library. Is there are ways to initiate it without asking a user " Please before start work write "`A::Table=nullptr`" " ???
And how to do `A::Table` in private section of class then?

I saw similar topics and did not find an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ static member variable and its initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547660/c-static-member-variable-and-its-initialization)

Comment: And why cannot you do it in your library sources? What is wrong with just `image* A::Table = nullptr;` ?

Comment: Can you say what you mean "do it in your library sourses"?

Comment: Can you explain why i need to write a type in initialization, when i write it in class? Its strange

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class A
{
private:
    static inline image* Table = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Dont work, i try it in VS2019, so may be its VS<2017

Comment: I forgot that you maybe use older C++ version. This code only work for C++17 and newer. You can go to setting and change the version of C++ (not VS version).

Comment: Usually, you should split to 2 files, .hpp for definition and .cpp for implimentation