# Why can't I use an integer variable as an array key when the array is declared constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

For reasons I don't understand, I can access a `constexpr` array's members using hard-coded integer literals as the index, but as soon as I try to use an integer *variable*, it fails to compile with the error `undefined reference`. But `aIvoryKeys` is in scope, and we can see this with hard-coded values.

```
class KeyboardKey{
   
public:
   
   static constexpr unsigned short int aIvoryKeys[] {0,2,4,5,7,9,11};
   
   void ShowIvory(){   
      
      // Hardcoded values work:
      std::cout << "aIvoryKeys " << aIvoryKeys[0] << std::endl; // 0
      std::cout << "aIvoryKeys " << aIvoryKeys[1] << std::endl; // 2
      std::cout << "aIvoryKeys " << aIvoryKeys[2] << std::endl; // 4
      
      // FAILS: undefined reference to `KeyboardKey::aIvoryKeys'
      int j = 2;
      std::cout << "aIvoryKeys " << aIvoryKeys[j] << std::endl; 
      
      // FAILS: undefined reference to `KeyboardKey::aIvoryKeys'
      for(int i=0;i<std::size(aIvoryKeys);++i){         
         std::cout << "aIvoryKeys " << aIvoryKeys[i] << std::endl;
      }
      
   }
   
};
```

If `static constexpr` is removed from the declaration, it compiles and runs.

The question is, why does declaring an array `static constexpr` seem to prevent local variables from being used to access it's members? The variable is local to the function and doesn't need any runtime information. And a `constexpr` array should be accessible at runtime anyway (it just doesn't change).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ static member variable and its initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547660/c-static-member-variable-and-its-initialization)

Comment: `i < sizeof(aIvoryKeys)` and `aIvoryKeys[i]` also makes this have _undefined behavior_. Use `i < std::size(aIvoryKeys)` instead. You could also use `inline static`, [example](https://godbolt.org/z/K6xGxWxrb)

Comment: Adding `inline` does seem to solve the problem. But I want to understand *why*. What is it actually doing to fix the problem, and what is the actual problem that `inline` is fixing? The other answer linked above assumes the reader knows what a "translation unit" is and how one works. I think it would be good to have an answer that explains in plain English why a variable that appears to be defined in scope is considered "undefined" unless you add the word `inline` before it. Right now, this seems like "magic" and I want to know what's actually happening and why.

Answer (score 2):

*"Hardcoded values work"*.

In fact no, clang spots the issue [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d4dd45df2b12d82)

In all cases, `aIvoryKeys` is ODR-used and so need a definition.

C++17 makes `aIvoryKeys` `inline`, and resolves that issue.