# How many instances are there of static data declared inside a static member function in a header file?

Tags: c++, static

I'm working on compiling [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) on AIX using `xlC`. Every checker class is derived from a `Check` class, whose constructor is responsible for registering that type of checker in a global static list.

Here's the relevant part of the code in question (filenames link to full source on Github):

### [check.h](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/lib/check.h)

```
class Check {
public:
    Check() {
        instances().push_back(this);
        instances().sort();
    }
    static std::list<Check *> &instances() {
        static std::list<Check *> _instances;
        return _instances;
    }
    // ...
};
```

### [checkbufferoverrun.h](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/lib/checkbufferoverrun.h)

```
class CheckBufferOverrun: public Check {
    // ...
};
```

### [checkbufferoverrun.cpp](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/lib/checkbufferoverrun.cpp)

```
// Register this check class (by creating a static instance of it)
namespace
{
CheckBufferOverrun instance;
}
```

Notice how the `_instances` static variable is declared inside a `static` function in the *header* file (there is no corresponding `check.cpp` file). When compiled with `g++`, the compiler and linker work together to ensure that there is only one implementation of the static `instances()` function, and therefore only one instance of the static `_instances` list. All the different checker classes instantiated in different `.cpp` files get registered in the same `_instances` list together.

However, under AIX's `xlC`, this same code ends up creating a *different* `instances()` function for every `.cpp` file in which it is included, which each having a different static `_instances` list. So there is no longer a single central `_instances` list, which causes Cppcheck to not run most of its checks.

Which compiler's behaviour is correct in this case?

**Update**: This question is not about how to *fix* the problem, I've already done that. I'm curious about which behaviour is *correct*.

Comment: This trick is called the Meyers Singleton, for those interested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

g++ has the correct behavior:  there should be exactly one instance of the object.  The C++ Standard says (C++03 7.1.2/4):

> A static local variable in an extern inline function always refers to the same object.

Because the class has external linkage, the static member function also has external linkage, per C++03 3.5/5:

> a member function...has external linkage if the name of the class has external linkage.

Because the member function is defined in the class definition, it is an inline function, per C++03 7.1.2/3:

> A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case g++ is correct (assuming that the `instances()` static member function returns a reference, that is a typo, right?). You might want to move the definition of the `instances()` function to a cpp file, that should be a work around in xlc.

Comment: Sorry, I typod when transcribing from the original source. The original source returns a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Correct it to:

```
   static std::list<Check *>& instances();

// check.cpp
 std::list<Check *> & Check::instances()
 {
     static std::list<Check *> _instances;
     return _instances;
 }
```

If you inline the function in the header file, each compilation unit will initially compile its own definition. However at link-time they should be reduced to one instance because of the  [One-Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c).

I am sure you are aware, of course, that your constructor to Check is not thread-safe. Your singleton constructor is also not totally thread-safe because although the ODR ensures the threads between them can only create one instance, the constructor of list is not atomic and therefore I am not sure it is guaranteed to be completely constructed before the other thread sees it.

For a totally thread-safe way of constructing singletons or non-atomic statics, you can use boost::once.