# ld: duplicate symbol

Tags: c++, makefile

I have rand.cpp and rand.hpp file and have rand_unif() function.
I have included rand.hpp file in sim_engine.hpp file.

In main.cpp file, I have included sim_engine.hpp file.
If I run makefile then I got this error

```
ld: duplicate symbol rand_unif()    in sim_engine.o and main.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

sim_engine.hpp is the only place where includes rand.hpp.
main.cpp does not include rand.hpp but sim_engine.hpp.

I don't understand why I am getting the duplicate symbol error.

```
#mod_simu.make project makefile

mod_simu : main.o rand.o graph.o street.o isection.o vehicle.o event.o FEL.o sim_engine.o clock.o
    g++ -o mod_simu main.o rand.o graph.o street.o isection.o vehicle.o event.o FEL.o sim_engine.o clock.o

main.o : main.cpp   
    g++ -c main.cpp

rand.o : rand.cpp
    g++ -c rand.cpp

graph.o : graph.cpp graph.hpp street.hpp isection.hpp
    g++ -c graph.cpp

street.o : street.cpp street.hpp
    g++ -c street.cpp

isection.o : isection.cpp isection.hpp street.hpp
    g++ -c isection.cpp

vehicle.o : vehicle.cpp vehicle.hpp
    g++ -c vehicle.cpp

event.o : event.cpp event.hpp
    g++ -c event.cpp

FEL.o : FEL.cpp FEL.hpp
    g++ -c FEL.cpp

sim_engine.o : sim_engine.cpp sim_engine.hpp
    g++ -c sim_engine.cpp

clock.o : clock.cpp clock.hpp
    g++ -c clock.cpp
clean:
    rm *.o mod_simu

#end
```

This is the makefile I have.

Comment: make sure you have header include guards

Comment: sounds like a violation of the [ODR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c)

Comment: in rand.hpp file I have #ifndef _RAND_HPP_
#define _RAND_HPP_ / #endif guards

Comment: Is `rand_unif()` defined in a header file? If so either move it to an implementation file or mark it `inline`.

Comment: @shuttle87: No. Header guards are not for combatting linker errors.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: The only correct answer so far. Shame it's not an answer..!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have evidently defined `rand_unif` multiple times in your program. You probably only define it once in textual code, but through header inclusion, that code gets compiled into multiple *.o* files.

You probably defined `rand_unif` in *rand.hpp*. That header gets included is included by *sim_engine.hpp*, so any .cpp file that includes *sim_engine.hpp* will automatically get a copy of `rand_unif`. Apparently, both *main.cpp* and *sim_engine.cpp* include *sim_engine.hpp*, so both those *.o* files get a copy of the function. C++ forbids having multiple definitions of the same function, but it does not require enforcement of that requirement. (It's called the *one-definition rule*.) The linker has caught you.

There are two typical solutions to the problem:

- Move the definition of the function into a *.cpp* file; *rand.cpp* seems like a good candidate. Make sure that *rand.hpp* contains only a declaration, not a definition.
- Change the definition in the header file to be *inline*. C++ makes an exception to the one-definition rule for inline functions. Add `inline` before the declaration in *rand.hpp*.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you are include the declaration of the function twice somewhere in your code. You may want to try wrapping all inclusions of "rand.hpp" with this:

> #ifndef RAND_HPP
>   #define RAND_HPP
>   #include {path to file}
>  #endif

Comment: That's true. But if you guard against multiple includes, then your preprocessor directives will ensure you won't be sending duplicated definitions to the compiler and linker.

But yes, in the case of defining it in separate .cpp files, macros will not provide any protection.