# C++, array declaration, templates, linker error

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

There is a linker error in my SW. I am using the following structure based on h, hpp, cpp files. Some classes are templatized, some not, some have function templates. The SW contains hundreds of included classes...

Declaration:

```
test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test
{
   public: 
        template <typename T>
        void foo1();

        void foo2 ();
};

#include "test.hpp" 

#endif
```

Definition:

```
test.hpp
#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP

template <typename T>
void Test::foo1() {}

inline void Test::foo2() {} //or in cpp file

#endif
```

CPP file:

```
test.cpp
#include "test.h"

void Test::foo2() {} //or in hpp file as inline
```

I have the following problem. The variable vars[] is declared in my h file

```
test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

char *vars[] = { "first", "second"...};

class Test
{
    public: void foo();
};

#include "test.hpp"

#endif
```

and used as a local variable inside foo() method defined in hpp file as inline.

```
test.hpp
#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP


inline void Test::foo() {
    char *var = vars[0];   //A Linker Error
}

#endif
```

However, the following linker error occurs:

```
Error   745 error LNK2005: "char * * vars" (?vars@@3PAPADA) already defined in main.obj
```

How and where to declare vars[] to avoid linker errors? After including

```
#include "test.hpp"
```

it is late to declare it...

As I wrote, the software contains a lot of cpp,  and hpp files included each other (all includes have been checked). It is not possible to send the whole example...

The main.obj represents a file which contains the main class.

Comment: Ifndef or ifndex? Are you getting a warning on that processor directive...? If it's not preventing double inclusion that might do it.  Also, try to compile with -E to figure out where that 2nd definition comes from.

Comment: @  RutgersMike: ifndef, of course, thanks, only a typo here...

Comment: just a few typos in the code. ifndex to ifndef, void foo2 () need ';' in the end. remove '...' from *vars[]...

Comment: @ billz. Thanks, checked and corrected (maybe),. Written without a compiler...

Comment: err, wheres's test2.obj then???

Comment: It doesn't look like you're giving the real definition of `class Test`. You can't have two classes with the same name. And you declare one with `foo1` and `foo2` member functions, and then another with a `foo` member function. Are those all the same `class Test` and do they all need to be folded together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `vars` in the header with extern linkage

```
extern const char* vars[];
```

and define it in exactly one source file

```
const char* vars[] = {"foo", "bar"};
```

Note the `const`, the conversion from string literals to `char*` is deprecated. The way you have it now, you're violationg the [One definition rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c) (You're redefining `vars` in every translation unit your header is included in).

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need this in test.hpp

```
extern char *vars[];
```

...and this in test.cpp

```
char *vars[] = { "first", "second"...};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not declaring two classes both named `Test`. If you are, that will cause you no end of problems. You are not allowed to do this.

So I assume the full declaration of `class Test` looks like this:

```
class Test
{
 public:
   void foo();

   template <typename T>
   void foo1();

   void foo2 ();
};
```

If this is the case, then your problem is clear.

You need to change the definition of `vars`. You need to have this in `test.h`:

```
extern char *vars[];
```

And this in `test.cpp`:

```
char *vars[] = { "first", "second"...};
```

Otherwise the compiler will think you're trying to declare a new version of `vars` in every file.