# No compiler/linker error for same name classes declared in different source files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, ambiguity, multiple-definition-error

I have 2 files as below, which declare a same name `class C`:

```
// C1.cpp
class C { 
public: void foo (int, float);
};

int main () {
  C c;
  c.foo(1, 2.3);
}

void C::foo (int, float) {}

// C2.cpp
class C { 
public:
  int i;  // <--- extra variable
  void foo (int, float);  // <--- non static
};

void foo () {
  C c;
  c.foo(0, 0.0);
  c.i = 0;
}
```

It compiles fine with `g++ C1.cpp C2.cpp`!

1. Why is there no compiler/linker error when only the names are same
   *but the bodies are not*?
2. Why the single definition of `C::foo(..)` serves for both the
   `static` and non-static versions?
3. Or if this is just another *undefined behavior* case from compiler,
   can we prevent it?

Comment: I think this is "UB and no diagnostic is required".

Comment: @downvoter, This question is not bad enough to be down voted.

Comment: Do you want a standard quote? It basically says "there can be more than one definition of a class but all of them need to consist of the same sequence of tokens" and "all the names inside the definition need to refer to the same entities". As Kerred said, the answer to 1) and 2) is UB, no diagnostic required. The answer to 3) is, I guess, just don't do it.

Comment: @jrok, I don't know what should be the answer. If you feel something can help, then post it. That will be helpful to me and future visitors. I couldn't find similar question in SO. Answer to (3) cannot be, "Just don't do it", when you have multiple people involved in a huge code base, in the worst case it has to be "Not possible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program violates [One definition rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c) and has undefined behaviour. From `n3337 3.2/5`, emphasis mine:

> **There can be more than one deﬁnition of a class type** (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with
>   external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member
>   of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not speciﬁed (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program **provided that each deﬁnition
>   appears in a different translation unit**, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>   such an entity named D deﬁned in more than one translation unit, then
>
> — **each deﬁnition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens;** and
>
> — **in each deﬁnition of D, corresponding names, looked up according
>   to 3.4, shall refer to an entity deﬁned within the deﬁnition of D, or
>   shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution** (13.3) and
>   after matching of partial template specialization (14.8.3), except
>   that a name can refer to a const object with internal or no linkage if
>   the object has the same literal type in all deﬁnitions of D, and the
>   object is initialized with a constant expression (5.19), and the value
>   (but not the address) of the object is used, and the object has the
>   same value in all deﬁnitions of D; and
>
> [*... omitted stuff that's not directly related to the example ...*]
>
> If the deﬁnitions of D satisfy all these requirements,
>   then the program shall behave as if there were a single deﬁnition of D. If the deﬁnitions of D do not satisfy
>   these requirements, then **the behavior is undeﬁned**.

You can't get a compiler error because it only "sees" one translation unit at a time. The linker and it's error messages are out of the scope of C++ standard, so I believe there can't be a *de iure* answer why it doesn't diagnose. I guess it just takes the first `C` symbol that encounters and discards the rest.