# Duplicate symbol and functions with static keyword

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, coding-style

I want to create a `Commons.h` file where I can put some shared info, constants, macros and helper functions.

This file has to be included in many part of my application.

If I create function with this syntax I get a `Duplicate Symbol` error:

```
int myFunction(int a){ 
   //do something..
}
```

While if I add the static keyword I get no errors.

```
static int myFunction(int a){ 
   //do something..
}
```

1) Is this a valid/right way to add helper functions to a project?
2) What happen exactly adding the `static` keyword at that definition?

Comment: [There can be only one!](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m1511oIe4O1rrs79co1_400.jpg) Definition of a function throughout the program, that is. Without the `static` keyword, you get a definition `MyFunction` in every place you include the header, and that's a violation of [One Definition Rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c).

Comment: @jrok Of course, there's also the option of using `inline`...

Comment: @Angew But that's not really a good idea unless you have performance problems otherwise.  The definition of a function does _not_ belong in a header.

Comment: you would be better off putting it all in a e.g. static library and have a header for the library, that way you do not duplicate code all over the place.

Comment: One of either the C++ or Objective-C tags is wrong.

Comment: @JeremyP this problem is valid for both Objective-C and C++.

Comment: @MatterGoal It's also valid for C and that's not there.

Comment: @JeremyP In that case I forgot one tag :P
What do you suggest to do?  I found this problem working with an Objective-C project but I suppose that is related with C++/C.

Comment: @MatterGoal If you edit your post, you can add tags.  However, now you've confirmed that it's OK to put the C tag in, I've already done it for you.

Comment: @MatterGoal, The semantic of those two example will be very different if there is static variable in the function scope. There will multiple instance of the static variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  You're creating a separate instance of the function
in every translation unit.  What you should do is only declare
the function in the header:

```
extern int myFunction( int a );
```

and define it in a source file somewhere.  (Note that the
`extern` above is optional, since it is implicit for all
function declarations, and it is usual to omit it.  I add it
here only to stress the fact that you are declaring, and not
defining.)

Comment: So if I want to create a set of helper functions, is a good practice to create the header with prototypes and just move the implementation in the source file. 

I saw that Apple in its implementation of CoreGraphics use the inline keyword for the most of its "helper" functions. So I just try to figured out which is the better way to do it.

Comment: @MatterGoal Putting the implementation in a separate source file is the usual solution.  Generally, `inline` should be avoided, as it increases coupling.  (The implementation of the function is visible in the header, which you want to avoid.)  It's more of an optimization technique, to be used when the profiler says you have to.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the keyword `static` before a function declaration, then you only can use this function **inside** the actual **translation unit** (.cpp, .c or .m), where it was defined.

So it is the opposite of the keyword `extern`, `extern` is the **default** storage class specifier for **functions**.

The use for a helper function is then wrong, because it doesn't even compile.

Instead you should declare the function in the helper file as extern. And use it without implementing it again. You can implement it once in the .c/.cpp/.m of the helper .h.

If you use a function as a helper function for other files, then it is good practice to use the `extern` keyword, even though it is not needed. It is a hint for programmers, this function is used somewhere else.

Comment: ??? His static wasn't on a class member (or at least he didn't say so if it was).  `static` is the opposite of `extern`, but only on free functions, not on members; `extern` isn't legal on class members.

Comment: He doesn't say it is a member of anything. What class?

Comment: I know.  But you talk about using the function "inside the actual class".  Anything inside a class is a member.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect.  static functions are accessible anywhere within the compilation unit (i.e. the `.c` or `.m` file being compiled)

Comment: Oh yes, I mean translation unit, thanks for correcting. Now I understand. Sorry @JamesKanze , my fault.

Comment: My function is not member of a class. Is just a generic helper function.

Comment: I know. But it is part of a translation unit, there declare it as extern or nothing (defaults to extern)