# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in MLPACK library with -std=c++11

Tags: c++11, boost, exc-bad-access, mlpack

I have encounter `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` error in my local environment (Mac OS X 10.9.2, boost 1.55.0, mlpack 1.0.8, llvm 5.1 clang-503.0.38), and I have narrowed down the error in a very simple snippet:

```
#include "mlpack/methods/range_search/range_search.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

The g++ version is

```
iMac:build dongli$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

and compile the snippet by

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main -lmlpack -I/usr/include/libxml2
```

(you may change to your case)

Run `main` in terminal will give you

```
iMac:build dongli$ ./main
Bus error: 10
```

and run it in `lldb` will give you more information

```
iMac:build dongli$ lldb ./main
Current executable set to './main' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 79449 launched: './main' (x86_64)
Process 79449 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xb4a75, 0x00000001000500eb libmlpack.1.0.dylib`long double boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64::lanczos_sum<long double>(long double const&) + 59, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100001d80)
    frame #0: 0x00000001000500eb libmlpack.1.0.dylib`long double boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64::lanczos_sum<long double>(long double const&) + 59
libmlpack.1.0.dylib`long double boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64::lanczos_sum<long double>(long double const&) + 59:
-> 0x1000500eb:  fstpt  (%rax)
   0x1000500ed:  fldt   0x26c8d(%rip)             ; .memset_pattern99 + 1296
   0x1000500f3:  fstpt  0x10(%rax)
   0x1000500f6:  fldt   0x26c94(%rip)             ; .memset_pattern99 + 1312
```

As you can see, it point me to `boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64::lanczos_sum`, but I have no idea what is the problem.

But when `-std=c++11` is absent, no error occurs. I also tried to reinstall `boost` with `--c++11` by `homebrew`.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have only installed one `boost`:

```
iMac:~ dongli$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/
1.55.0
```

with command:

```
brew install boost --c++11
```

Answer (score 1):

You could 
check that the actual shared library file is marked `executable` and is accessible to the user that runs the application?

It that isn't it, this probably means that at runtime you find a conflicting version of the library. Fix/override the runtime library path, or compile against the same version of the library if so

Comment: I can assure that there is no conflicting version of the library, since I only installed `boost` and `mlpack` from `homebrew`.

Comment: Then my money is squarely on the permissions

Comment: But the error is gone when no `-std=c++11` option is present.

Comment: Then you **do** have a conflicting version of Boost installed. Apparently the homebrew version **wasn't** compiled with --std=c++11. This will result in code violating the **[ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c

Comment: @LiDong by the way, that information is missing from the question.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention it!

Answer (score 0):

After I removed all the C++11 features from my codes (e.g., initializer_list and default template argument), and removed the `-std=c++11` option, the error is gone. I think I have installed `boost`, `mlpack` with `-std=c++11` by using `homebrew`, but the error persisted, so my experience is not use the new features if they are not necessary.