# Accessing variables from another source file C++?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm trying to avoid classes, so keep that in mind.

I want to know how to access a variable from another .cpp file.

For whatever reason when I try to include the variable in my 'codeReferences.h' header file I get LNK 2005 errors. So I'm wondering without defining it within a globally used header file (causes errors) how can I access variables from another .cpp file.

All answers appreciated.

Comment: You can access a variable from another .cpp file by `#include`ing it. Or, if you plan to **declare** the variables in your *another .cpp file*, you can declare your variables using `extern`.

Comment: Curious why you are trying to avoid classes.

Comment: `#include` on another .cpp file does not access the other unit's variables, it makes new ones (causing UB in the process)

Answer (score 6):

`LNK2005` says that you have multiple definitions for the same symbol.

You need to understand the difference between a declaration and a definition:

- When you declare a variable, then you only tell the compiler that there's a name (=symbol) and the type of that symbol.
- When you assign a concrete value to a variable or provide an implementation for it then you define it (e.g. in case of functions).

You can have an arbitrary number of declarations for a symbol, but you must only have one definition for it. See this thread too: [What exactly is One Definition Rule in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c)

If you want to use the same symbol in several .cpp files (referring to the same object), then you need to use the `extern` keyword in the header file:

Example:

```
/** header.h **/
extern int i;
```

You can include this header in any number of .cpp files to introduce the symbol `i`. You must specify a definition for `i` only in one .cpp:

```
/** code.cpp **/
#include "header.h"
int i; // this is a definition, even if you do not initialize here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably by ".cpp file" you mean "translation unit".

The holy C++ standard couldn't care less how the code is distributed in files, and has no notion of header files versus .cpp.

A variable to be defined in one translation unit and accessed in another, must have `extern` linkage. This is the default for namespace level non-`const` variables. However, an ordinary declaration will also *define* the variable, and then you run into the [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c) that in general requires a single **definition** of each thing.

A solution is to write e.g.

```
extern int n_oranges;
```

in the translation unit where you just want to access the variable. The explicit mention of `extern` linkage, without an initializer, makes this a **pure declaration**.

You can have as many pure declarations of something, as you want.

It's best to put such a declaration in a header file, so as to avoid redundant multiple possibly not quite matching declarations. Note that in a header file it will be included as part of each relevant translation unit's text. The C++ compiler doesn't care where it comes from, just that it's there.

---

Relevant standardese:

***C++11 §3.1/2:***

> **”** A declaration is a *definition* unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body (8.4), it
>   contains the `extern` specifier (7.1.1) or a *linkage-specification* (7.5) and neither an *initializer* nor a *function-body*, it declares a static data member in a class definition (9.2, 9.4), it is a class name declaration (9.1), it is an *opaque-enum-declaration* (7.2), it is a *template-parameter* (14.1), it is a *parameter-declaration* (8.3.5) in a
>   function declarator that is not the *declarator* of a *function-definition*, or it is a `typedef` declaration (7.1.3),
>   an *alias-declaration* (7.1.3), a *using-declaration* (7.3.3), a *static_assert-declaration* (Clause 7), an *attribute-declaration* (Clause 7), an *empty-declaration* (Clause 7), or a *using-directive* (7.3.4).

Answer (score 0):

Now the first thing is you should be careful you don't define things multiple times.

Second you  should at least have read a tutorial on the basics of the c++ programming language.

I know I may sound harsh but a simple tutorial could help you understand the language a lot better than you currently do.

To be able to access variables from a different source file you can include them using their extension. For better practices most developers use headers to define the code , and the source to actually make it function to be able to easily debug and change things without having massive files to go through.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29578272/edit) your answer and add this update there instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that I shall do that