# Already defined error with operator overloading

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

When debugging my program I keep getting these two errors:

> main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_istream > & __cdecl operator>>(class std::basic_istream > &,class Complex &)" (??5@YAAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAVComplex@@@Z) already defined in Imaginary.obj
>
> 1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream > &,class Complex const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABVComplex@@@Z) already defined in Imaginary.obj

I have tried restarting my project to make sure that I created a console application and not something else on accident but that didn't work. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

imaginary.h

```
#ifndef imaginary_h_
#define imaginary_h_

#include <iostream>

class Complex
{    
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream& os, const Complex&);
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream& is, Complex&);

private:    
    double real;
    double imag;
    char op;

public:    
    double r = real;
    double i = imag;
    char o = op;

    Complex()
    {    
    }

    Complex(double r, double i, char o)
    {    
    }

    bool userTest();    
};

#endif

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Complex & complex)    
{
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, Complex & complex)    
{
    is >> complex.r >> complex.o >> complex.i;
    return is;
}
```

Imaginary.cpp

```
#include "imaginary.h"    
#include <iostream>

bool Complex::userTest()

{
    if (op == '+' || op == '-')

    {
        return true;
    }

    else

    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect operand entry, please enter complex number as x+yi" << "/n" << "/n";

                return false;
    }

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "imaginary.h"

#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    double userInput;

    std::cout << "Here you will add or subtract complex numbers." << "/n" << "/n";

    do

    {

        std::cout << "Please enter the real part of you complex number: " << "/n" << "/n";

                Complex complex;

        std::cin >> complex;

        std::cout << "/n" << "/n" << "/n/t" << "Note: Remember to enter your complex number in the format of x+yi to avoid an error";

                if (complex.userTest())
                {
                    std::cout << complex << "/n" << "/n";
                }

        std::cout << "Would you like to perform another complex number operation? " << "/n" << "/n/t";

                        std::cout << "Choose 1 for Yes and 2 for No" << "/n" << "/n";

        std::cin >> userInput;

    } while (userInput == 1);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your file boundaries? Are the `operator<<` and `operator>>` definitions in the *header*?

Comment: Please divide the code into files and fix your string literals (which span multiple lines).

Comment: The variables `i` and `r` will be initialized with the uninitialized values of `imag` and `real` only once.  If you want to have `i` and `r` to reflect the changing values of `imag` and `real`, you will have to update `i` and `r` whenever `imag` and `real` are updated.  So, why bother with the copies?  You could, if you must, declare `i` and `r` as *references* to `imag` and `r`.  But then ask yourself why you need copies?  Are you trying to do something like *getter* and *setter* functions? Same principle applies to `o` and `op`.

Comment: You seriously need to validate the `complex.o` variable before returning.  For example, your code allows these inputs as valid entries:  4M6i, 4*6i, 4@6i, 4z6i.

Answer (score 14):

You have two options:

1. Move implementation of operator methods to a single cpp file
2. Or declare the implementations as `inline`.

For example, in your header file, *imaginary.hpp*:

```
inline // <-- Add this line 
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Complex & complex)    
{
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}

inline  // <-- Add this line 
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, Complex & complex)    
{
    is >> complex.r >> complex.o >> complex.i;
    return is;
}

#endif  // imaginary_h_  <-- This line was moved.
```

Or you can simply move the implementations into your *imaginary.cpp* file.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have defined

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &complex) {
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, Complex &complex) {
    is >> complex.r >> complex.o >> complex.i;
    return is;
}
```

in your header file and because this is included in `imaginary.cpp` and `main.cpp` they are defined multiple times. This violates the [single definition rule of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c).

You need to move the implementation of `operator <<` and `operator >>` to the `.cpp` file and only leave the declaration in the header file. This would mean having

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &complex);

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, Complex &complex);
```

in the header file after the definition of the class

```
class Complex {
    ...
};
```

and before the ending `#endif`. Then in `imaginary.cpp` you would have the definition

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Complex &complex) {
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &is, Complex &complex) {
    is >> complex.r >> complex.o >> complex.i;
    return is;
}
```

Comment: No. Include guards do not prevent multiple definitions. They _must_ be moved to a `.cpp` unless marked `inline` (or `static`; ew)

Comment: okay so I did that but I am still receiving the error messages. They now also include this one:fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was where I was going with my edit.

Comment: Your edit says it's an alternative approach. No, it's the only approach.

Comment: Ugh @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry yes, got it all backwards! I'll fix it now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That should be it fixed now. Probably time to call it a day now!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for mentioning that include guards do not prevent multiple definitions! It really helped me!

Answer (score -1):

Your error lies in your header guard:

```
    bool userTest();    
};

#endif // Here!

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Complex & complex)    
{
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}
```

When you include the header in your two file, they each compile the function in their respective compilation unit. That's why there's an error at link time.

Your file should look like this:

```
#ifndef imaginary_h_
#define imaginary_h_

#include <iostream>

class Complex
{    
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream& os, const Complex&);
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream& is, Complex&);

private:    
    double real;
    double imag;
    char op;

public:    
    double r = real;
    double i = imag;
    char o = op;

    Complex()
    {    
    }

    Complex(double r, double i, char o)
    {    
    }

    bool userTest();    
};

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Complex & complex)    
{
    os << complex.r << complex.o << complex.i << "i" << "/n" << "/n";
    return os;
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & is, Complex & complex)    
{
    is >> complex.r >> complex.o >> complex.i;
    return is;
}

#endif
```

But two other things:

1. You should not put function definition in you header. You should put it in your cpp file
2. You should seek to add `#pragma once` in addition of your header guard. It should prevent some error while keeping a standard code.

Comment: No. Include guards do not prevent multiple definitions.