# Does the standard specify which functions are declared inline?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

So the question is, does the latest standard specify when a function in the standard C++ library is declared inline or not?

Looking at the `algorithm` header file from the Clang, GCC and MSVC implementations, every single function, except for the ones which are constexpr, are declared inline.

I was gonna go on and ask about when to inline and what not, but I don't wanna have the usual argument about how the compiler knows better or micro optimizations, so I probably shouldn't even let this sentence stay in the question. Oh wait...

Comment: Even if the finished specification costs money, the [drafts are available](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) so you can check yourself. The last draft before ratification is usually the same as the finished standards text (the only difference being some blurb that's not important).

Comment: `inline` is about the ODR, not about inlining calls. And, no, it doesn't; it's up to the implementation.

Comment: `<algorithm>` is part of the implementation, and doesn't necessarily follow strict C++ rules anyway. The most important rule which is almost always violated is the use of `_[A-Z]` prefixes - you can't, an implementation must.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The implementation author chooses.

> `[C++14: 17.6.5.4/1]:` It is unspecified whether any global or non-member functions in the C++ standard library are defined as `inline` (7.1.2).
>
> `[C++14: 17.6.5.5/1]:` It is unspecified whether any member functions in the C++ standard library are defined as `inline` (7.1.2).

And recall that this has nothing to do with actual inlining nowadays; it really only affects the ODR.

Comment: Can you expand on how it affects the ODR and whatnot? A small example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DeiDei http://stackoverflow.com/q/4192170/212870. Or you could always look it up yourself.