# Can a C function declaration have more than one identifier?

Tags: c, signals, function-pointers, typedef

There's a C function declaration `signal` from [c-faq website](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) example 3:

```
void (*signal(int, void (*fp)(int)))(int);
```

I wonder how can there be two identifiers `signal`, `fp` and it still passes compilation (I added this line randomly in my existing code and it compiles successfully)?

Comment: [Does redefining a function from the standard library violate the one-definition rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670800/does-redefining-a-function-from-the-standard-library-violate-the-one-definition)

Comment: `void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);` is a [function (int, pointer to function (int) returning void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*signal%28int%2C+void+%28*%29%28int%29%29%29%28int%29%3B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a C function declaration/prototype cannot have any more than one identifier. Refer to the reference page and example code for `signal` on cplusplus.com here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/.

In this declaration:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

we are declaring a function called `signal` which returns a *pointer to* a function which returns `void` and accepts an `int`--ie: a *pointer to* a function like this:

```
void func(int);
```

The inputs to the `signal` function are 1st, an `int`, and 2nd, a pointer to a function which returns a `void` and accepts an `int`--again, a *pointer to* a function like `func` above. Now, in C, when declaring a function which returns a pointer to a function and accepts a pointer to a function, it gets all goobly-ga-gook-looking (garbled and confusing looking), which is why we all have confusion initially (and again and again frequently) looking at function declarations like `signal`. A couple much much much clearer ways to define a function like `signal` in C, to make this all crystal-clear, are like this, instead, both of which are identical to the goobly-gook-looking one:

```
// 1. typedef a function--call it `func_t` for "func type"
typedef void func_t(int);

// 2. Use the typedef above to define `signal`
func_t* signal(int sig, func_t* fp); // Ah, now this makes sense!
```

OR

```
// 1. typedef a *pointer to* a function--call it `func_p` for "pointer to a func type"
typedef void (*func_p)(int);

// 2. Use the typedef above to define `signal`
func_p signal(int sig, func_p fp); // Ah, now this makes sense too!
```

**And remember, what you call each input parameter type in a function *declaration* is irrelevant in C and *doesn't even have to match between a header and source file.***

Ex:

**my_module.h:**

```
// Any of these 3 prototypes are equivalent, valid, and identical
// (although using sensible names which match between the header &
// source files is most clear and helpful to the reader!):
func_p signal(int sig, func_p fp);
func_p signal(int signal, func_p whatsupdude);
func_p signal(int, func_p);
```

**my_module.c:**

```
func_p signal(int sig, func_p fp)
{
    // define the function here
}
```

Now, how did I initially figure all this out?
Ans: I looked at [the example code from cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/). It helped a TON to make this all clear, as you can see how the return value from `signal` is assigned to `prev_handler`, which is a pointer to a function, and you can see how `my_handler`, which is defined as a function, is passed in as the 2nd parameter to `signal`! For kicks, I should probably also mention that these 2 lines are identical, and both are perfectly valid:

```
prev_handler = signal (SIGINT, my_handler);
prev_handler = signal (SIGINT, &my_handler);
```

This is because if you pass in a function as a parameter the compiler knows to just take its address anyway.

[Cplusplus example code:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/)

```
/* signal example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <signal.h>     /* signal, raise, sig_atomic_t */

sig_atomic_t signaled = 0;

void my_handler (int param)
{
  signaled = 1;
}

int main ()
{
  void (*prev_handler)(int);

  prev_handler = signal (SIGINT, my_handler);

  /* ... */
  raise(SIGINT);
  /* ... */

  printf ("signaled is %d.\n",signaled);


  return 0;
}
```

### References:

1. Reminder about how to typedef functions and function pointers, since this is confusing to pretty much everybody and requires re-verifying from time to time: http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Typedef_Function_Type

Answer (score 3):

The name `fp` is commonly used for variables of type `FILE *`, but it could be used for all sorts of other purposes (floating-point, fishery protection, function pointer, …).

The function declaration in the question is equivalent to the declaration of [`signal()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1) in the C standard except that it uses `fp` where the standard uses `func`, and the standard gives the name `sig` to the first argument to `signal()`.

You could delete the `fp` from the function declaration (prototype); nothing significant changes:

```
void (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);
```

You could also use meaningful names for arguments throughout:

```
void (*signal(int signum, void (*handler)(int signum)))(int signum);
```

Each occurrence of `signum` identifies where a signal number is provided.  The first argument to `signal()` itself is a signal number; the argument to `handler` indicates that the handler function will be called with the signal number; and the outermost `signum` indicates that the function pointer returned by `signal()` is of the same type as `handler` and should be (is) passed a signal number when called.

See also [Understanding typedefs for function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1591361/15168).