# Unable to pass macro definition to base class

Tags: c++, c++14

Base class is not able to view the macros defined in the derived class on the creation of derived class object. [C++14]

Base.HPP

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        #ifndef SKIP
        std::cout << "Bing" << std::endl;
        #endif
    }
};
```

File : Derived.HPP

```
#define SKIP
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
};
```

So, whenever I create the object of Derived class I expected not to see the `Bing` in the output terminal since I have defined the macro `SKIP`.

But this does not happens. It seems Base class is clueless about the definition of macro `SKIP`. Is there a way to do it or this is not possible to do it without compiling the code with `-DSKIP` flag?

Comment: Don't use macros?

Comment: include files are typically processed only once, so if SKIP isn't defined at the point it is processed, then "Bing" won't appear.

Comment: Macros do text replacement before the compiler gets to see the code. If you make a [mcve] people might be able to help you, right now we can't even tell if you `#define`d `SKIP` before or after `#include`ing *Base.HPP* which is important. Also you are probably violating the [ODR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170) and are on the way to [UB](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1812/undefined-behavior#t=201702271913219429673).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, don't use macros.

Second, `SKIP` will be checked for defined-ness at the time that the class declaration of `Base` is processed - not when the class declaration of `Derived` is processed, so if you `#define` it where you are, it's just too late. You need to do it way earlier:

```
#define SKIP
#include "Base.hpp"

class Derived : public Base { ... };
```

But make sure you define or don't define `SKIP` the same way before every inclusion of `Base`, or it's an ODR-violation. Or simply define it on the command line.

But, really, don't use macros. Pass a `bool`.

Comment: And if you really, really, really have to use a macro, make it a long and ugly name so it won't clash with anything else out there, e. g. "SKIP_COUT_IN_THIS_CLASS_OF_MY_SUPER_COOL_LIBRARY" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates instead of macros :

```
template<bool skip>
struct Base {};

template<>
struct Base<false> {
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Bing" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then, when creating your `Derived` class, you do this:

```
struct Derived : Base<true> {};
```

If you put `true` as the template parameter, it will select the other base class that output `Bing`.

Comment: To the downvoter: what is wrong with my answer? I'm trying to show another way OP can achieve what he want. Is there a way I can improve my answer?