# C++ - call function with variable pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I tried to outsource some functions in *another.cpp* but if I change `someObject` in *another.cpp*, it has to effect `someObject` in *main.cpp*.
So this is basically the structure now. Which doesn't affect `camera`.

---

**main.cpp**

```
someObject camera;
setCamera(someObject camera);

int main()
{
    setCamera(camera);
    camera.doSomething();
}
```

---

**another.cpp**

```
someObject tempCamera;

void setCamera(someObject camera)
{
    tempCamera = camera;
}

void anotherFunction()
{
    tempCamera.doSomethingElse();
}
```

so what I want to do is making `tempCamera` pointing to `camera`,

but when I do it like this:

```
someObject *tempCamera;

void setCamera(someObject camera)
{
    tempCamera = &camera;
}

anotherFunction()
{
    tempCamera.doSomethingElse();
}
```

I get an error, that the expression must have a `class` type.
My Question now is: How do I call a function from a pointer or what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You are running afoul of the [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c). You probably want to refer to the same `someObject tempCamera;` in both files, which you can do by marking all but one declaration as `extern`.

main.cpp

```
someObject camera;
setCamera(someObject camera);

int main()
{
   setCamera(camera);
   camera.doSomething();
}
```

another.cpp

```
extern someObject tempCamera;

void setCamera(someObject camera)
{
   tempCamera = camera;
}

void anotherFunction(){
   tempCamera.doSomethingElse();
}
```

third.cpp

```
extern someObject tempCamera;

void yetFurtherFunction(){
   tempCamera.doSomethingDifferent();
}
```

Repeating this declaration will soon get tedious, so it is common to put the `extern` declartion in a header file that is `#include`d in multiple .cpp files (a.k.a. *Translation Units*)

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thank you for your help. My mind was totally set to complicated mode I overlooked the simple things.