# Need help inserting a string into a function

Tags: c++, string, function

I am looking to make repeated programming a little bit easier going forward. The program tells a motor to spin based on the manufacturers program guidelines. The current code will state:

```
motorname.spin(originallib::directionType::fwd, speed, originallib::velocityUnits::pct);
```

I want to be able to say:

```
int main()
{
run(LeftFront,80);
run(RightFront,80);
}

void run(string motorname, double speed )
{
motorname.spin(originallib::directionType::fwd, speed, originallib::velocityUnits::pct);
}
```

LeftFront and RightFront have been declared in a previous header file as

```
originallib::motor LeftFront=originallib::motor(originallib::PORT2,
                                                originallib::gearSetting::ratio18_1,
                                                true);
```

The issue I am running into is:

> "error: no member named 'spin' in 'std::basic_string' "

Because the `motorname.spin`..... is part of the originallib

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: `void run(string motorname, double speed )` tells the compiler that `motorname` is a `std::string`, not whatever class it's supposed to be.  You want `void run(SomeClassHere motorname, double speed )`

Comment: What is the type of LeftFront and RightFront?

Comment: Here is how they are defined in the header:

 `originallib::motor LeftFront=originallib::motor(originallib::PORT2,originallib::gearSetting::ratio18_1,true);`

Answer (score 0):

```
void run(string motorname, double speed )
```

Tells the compiler that `motorname` is a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). `std::string` has no `spin` method.  Based on

```
run(LeftFront,80);
```

where `LeftFront` is a `originallib::motor`, and assuming `originallib::motor` does indeed have a `spin` method, you really the function to look something like

```
void run(originallib::motor & motor, 
         double speed)
{
    motor.spin(originallib::directionType::fwd, 
               speed, 
               originallib::velocityUnits::pct);
}
```

so that a `motor` that can `spin` is provided instead of a `string` that can at best [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

An alternative using names would be to have a map of `string`->`motor` key-value pairs that you can look up a motor name in the map and receive the mapped  `motor`, on which you could invoke `spin`. This does not seem to be a desirable  case here.

## Sidenote:

You do not want to

```
originallib::motor LeftFront=originallib::motor(originallib::PORT2,
                                                originallib::gearSetting::ratio18_1,
                                                true);
```

in a header. This plays havoc on the [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c) if multiple [Translation Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) include the header as each including translation unit will have its own, equally valid, `LeftFront`. [Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) will not prevent this because an include guard can only prevent a header from being included multiple times in one translation unit.