# getting "error: redefinition of class" in cpp file even though I am not trying to redefine a class

Tags: c++

I was coding something as a little practice and I kept getting this error:

> error: redefinition of a "LabMouse::LabMouse(std::__cxx::string,int)

It's saying that it was already defined in my `.h` file, which it is. I'm just confused on why it's saying that I'm trying to redefine it within my `.cpp` file?

The `.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LabMouse.h" 

LabMouse::LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage){

}

void LabMouse::speak(){
        std::cout << "Narf!" << std::endl;
}

LabMouse::~LabMouse(){
        std::cout << "LabMouse Destructor" << std::endl;
}

void LabMouse::setName(std::string name){
        name = "Pinky";
}

void LabMouse::sayHello(){
        std::cout << "LabMouse Name: " << aname << " ,age: " << aage << std::endl;
}
```

The `.h` file

```
#ifndef LABMOUSE_H
#define LABMOUSE_H
#include <string>

class LabMouse{
private:
        std::string aname = "";
        int aage = 1;
public:
        LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage){

        }
        void speak();
        void setName(std::string aname);
        void sayHello();


        virtual ~LabMouse();
};

#endif
```

Comment: The error is correct.  You define the `LabMouse` constructor in the header, and again in the cpp file.  This violates the [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c).  The **complete** error message should also be telling you [the exact line where this is happening](https://godbolt.org/z/5brKKr3dv).

Comment: You did provide a body for `LabMouse::LabMoude(std::string, int)` in the class definition. If this isn't on purpose, you need to replace the constructor body with a semicolon in the header...

Comment: Note that you are not _trying to redefine a class_, you are actually trying to redefine a **constructor**

Comment: You have to read error message very carefullly; that takes practice. The compiler is complaining about `LabMouse::LabMouse`, which is the constructor for the class `LabMouse`.

Answer (score 2):

In the header file remove the braces (thereby turning your definition into a declaration), otherwise you are providing an implementation

```
LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage){
}
```

should just be

```
LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage);
```

because you have an implementation already in the cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a *body* for `LabMouse()` in the `.h` file, and you are defining *another body* for `LabMouse()` in the `.cpp` file.  Hence the error.  You need to get rid of one of those bodies.

Also, your constructor is not initializing the `aname` and `aage` class members with the values of the input parameters.

Use this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LabMouse.h" 

LabMouse::LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage)
    : name(aname), age(aage) {
}

void LabMouse::speak() const {
    std::cout << "Narf!" << std::endl;
}

LabMouse::~LabMouse() {
    std::cout << "LabMouse Destructor" << std::endl;
}

void LabMouse::setName(const std::string &aname) {
    name = aname;
}

void LabMouse::sayHello() const {
    std::cout << "LabMouse Name: " << name << ", age: " << age << std::endl;
}
```

```
#ifndef LABMOUSE_H
#define LABMOUSE_H
#include <string>

class LabMouse{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age = 1;
public:
    LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage);
    virtual ~LabMouse();

    void speak() const;
    void setName(const std::string &aname);
    void sayHello() const;
};

#endif
```

Or this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LabMouse.h" 

void LabMouse::speak() const {
    std::cout << "Narf!" << std::endl;
}

LabMouse::~LabMouse() {
    std::cout << "LabMouse Destructor" << std::endl;
}

void LabMouse::setName(const std::string &aname) {
    name = aname;
}

void LabMouse::sayHello() const {
    std::cout << "LabMouse Name: " << name << ", age: " << age << std::endl;
}
```

```
#ifndef LABMOUSE_H
#define LABMOUSE_H
#include <string>

class LabMouse{
private:
    std::string name;
    int age = 1;
public:
    LabMouse(const std::string aname, const int aage)
        : name(aname), age(aage)
    {
    }

    virtual ~LabMouse();

    void speak() const;
    void setName(const std::string &aname);
    void sayHello() const;
};

#endif
```