# How to implement Singleton C++ the right way

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to implement a class with the Singleton Pattern in C++. But I get following linking error:

projectgen.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Metadata::metadata'; C:\Users\adria\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdq4ZjN.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What's the error's cause?

Metadata.h: (Singleton class)

```
#pragma once
class Metadata
{
public:

    Metadata(Metadata &other) = delete;
    void operator=(const Metadata &other) = delete;

    static Metadata *getInstance()
    {
        return metadata;
    }

    static void createInstance(Ctor &params)
    {
        if (!metadata)
        {
            metadata = new Metadata(params);
        }
    }
protected:
    Metadata(Ctor &params)
    {
        m_vars = params;
    }

    static Metadata *metadata;

private:
    Ctor m_vars;
}

Metadata* Metadata::metadata = nullptr;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "metadata.h"

int main(void)
{
    Ctor ctor;
    Metadata::createInstance(ctor);
    Metadata* data = Metadata::getInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

projectgen.cpp:

```
#include "metadata.h"

void ProjectGenerator::test()
{
    Metadata* data = Metadata::getInstance();
}
```

Comment: `Metadata* Metadata::metadata = nullptr;` cannot be in the header file, it needs to be in a  ".cpp" file

Comment: You need to instantiate the static variable `metadata` somewhere in a cpp file not in an .h file. There error is surely caused because you have metadata.h included somewhere else.

Comment: Reopened, not a duplicate. This is simply a coding error. It has nothing to do with singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `#include` statement is logically equivalent to taking the included header file and physically inserting it into the `.cpp` file that's including it.

```
Metadata* Metadata::metadata = nullptr;
```

In the included header file, this defines this particular static class member. Therefore, every `.cpp` file that includes this header file defines this class member. You have two `.cpp` files that include this header file, and each one defines the same static class member.

This violates C++'s [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c). An object can be defined exactly once.

Simply move this definition to one of your `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, I just want the option to declare the variable `inline`. This allows multiple definitions which are then taken as one.

`inline Metadata* Metadata::metadata = nullptr;`