# Error redefinition of static class member and method in C++ linked to multiple file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a header file:

```
#ifndef __DATABASE_HELPER_H__
#define __DATABASE_HELPER_H__
    
class DatabaseHelper{
    public: 
        static QJsonDocument* database;
        DatabaseHelper();
        static Card* selectJSonCard(std::string cardCode);
        static void testFunctions();
        static bool isLeader(std::string cardCode);
};

#endif

QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());

void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions(){
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
//and so on for the others
```

Now, I need it to be included from two different files.

With one file is fine, it compiles, but 2 files gives me this error:

```
[ERROR] ./models/../utils/database_helper.h:38:16: error: redefinition of ‘QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database’
   38 | QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./utils/database_helper.h:38:16: note: ‘QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database’ previously declared here
   38 | QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./models/../utils/database_helper.h:114:6: error: redefinition of ‘static void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions()’
  114 | void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./utils/database_helper.h:114:6: note: ‘static void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions()’ previously defined here
  114 | void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Where the first file including this is in folder `./models/` and the other one is in `./`.

My goal is to be able to access the `static` function from every file in which I include the header, and have just one instance of the `QJsonDocument` variable `database`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Move the definition `QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());
` to source file.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__DATABASE_HELPER_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());
```

This defines `DatabaseHelper::database`.

Every `.cpp` file that includes this header file will define this object. An `#include` directive logically inserts the header file into the including `.cpp` files. It's as if every one of your `.cpp` files, that includes this header file, defines this. That's how `#include` works in C++.

Therefore, when two or more `.cpp` files include this header file, this results in violation of the [One Definition Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-exactly-is-one-definition-rule-in-c), hence your compilation error.

The solution is trivial. Move all definitions into exactly one of your `.cpp` files.

The same thing applies to `void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions()`, too.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that you've put the definition `QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());` inside the header file instead of a source file. So when that header is included in different source files, that definition also gets duplicated and hence the error.

To solve this move `QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &(QJsonDocument());` to a **single** source file. This way you will only have a **declaration** inside the header and having multiple *declaration* is fine(as opposed to having multiple definitions) while the corresponding **definition** will be inside a source file.

Answer (score 0):

As several others have stated, you are *defining* `DatabaseHelper::database` in the header file, which means that every translation unit which includes the header will get its own copy of `DatabaseHelper::database`, hence the redefinition error during linking.

I want to point out that `&(QJsonDocument())` should not even compile, as you can't take the address of a temporary object.  The correct way is to create an object whose lifetime is at least as long as `DatabaseHelper::database`, and then you can take the address of that object, eg:

```
static QJsonDocument obj;
QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::database = &obj;
```

That being said, a better option is to not have a `static` pointer member at all.  The customary approach to creating a singleton class is to use a `static` method which returns a pointer/reference to the singleton (and make the constructor `private` so that no code outside of the class can instantiate the singleton directly), and then inside that `static` method you can define the actual singleton as a `static` object, eg:

.h

```
#ifndef __DATABASE_HELPER_H__
#define __DATABASE_HELPER_H__
    
class DatabaseHelper{
    private:
        DatabaseHelper();

    public: 
        static QJsonDocument* GetDatabase(); // <-- HERE
        static Card* selectJSonCard(std::string cardCode);
        static void testFunctions();
        static bool isLeader(std::string cardCode);
};

#endif
```

.cpp

```
DatabaseHelper::DatabaseHelper(){
}

QJsonDocument* DatabaseHelper::GetDatabase(){
    static QJsonDocument database; // <-- HERE
    return &database;
}

void DatabaseHelper::testFunctions(){
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}

//and so on for the others
```