# Why does defining a static class object in C++ cause a "multiple definition" error?

Tags: static, rgb, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I am currently making a program in Arduino IDE to make animations with LEDs. My concept is that there is a base Animation class that holds the static RGBLed object that allows me to light up LEDs in the draw() method. All the children of Animation are supposed to inherit this object and the method. This is my **Animation.cpp**:

```
#include <RGBLed.h>

const int GPIN = D0, RPIN = D1, BPIN = D2; //RGB MOSFET pins


class Animation{
protected:
  int R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
  static RGBLed myLED;

public:
  void update(int currentTime){}

  void draw(){
    myLED.setColor(R, G, B);
  }
};
RGBLed Animation::myLED(RPIN, GPIN, BPIN, RGBLed::COMMON_CATHODE);


class Animation1: public Animation{
private:
  int timer = 0;
  int anim_time = 1000;
  
public:
  Animation1(){
    timer = millis();
  }

  void update(int currentTime){
    //do some RGB magic
    }
  }
};


class RGBSwipe: public Animation{
private:
  float H = 0.0, S = 1.0, V = 1.0;
  int timer = 0;
  int delay_time = 10;

public:
  RGBSwipe(){
    timer = millis();
  }

  void update(int currentTime){
    //do some HSV magic
    }
  }

private:
  void HSVtoRGB(){
    //Conversion happens here
  }
};
```

I get this error:

> (USER)/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/3.1.0-gcc10.3-e5f9fec/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/10.3.0/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: (USER)\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-3EC4D14CA84EC5BABE4C744AA5D32B6B\sketch\FFT_analyzer.ino.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN9Animation5myLEDE+0x0): multiple definition of `_ZN9Animation5myLEDE'; (USER)\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-3EC4D14CA84EC5BABE4C744AA5D32B6B\sketch\Animation.cpp.o:(.bss._ZN9Animation5myLEDE+0x0): first defined here
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> exit status 1
>
> Compilation error: exit status 1

I tried re-locating the definition but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas?

Comment: Move the line `RGBLed Animation::myLED(RPIN, GPIN, BPIN, RGBLed::COMMON_CATHODE);` into the `.cpp` file. This is the definition of the variable, and can only be done in a single translation unit.

Comment: @prapin It works but why? Why defining it in the main file differ from what I have done? Isn't including the .cpp file just copy and pasting it into the main file?

Comment: I now understand your original error.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting situation haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.cpp`, you have a `#include "Animation.cpp"`.

**Don't do that**.

*Never `#include` an implementation `.cpp` file*, only header files `.h` or `.hpp`. There are exceptions to that rule for advanced uses, like creation of an amalgamation, but this is only for expert C++ programmers.

All `.cpp` files shall be compiled separately. This is what is called a *compilation unit*. In your situation, the content of `Animation.cpp` was compiled twice, once for its own and once inside `main.cpp`. Ans the linker has two copies for each identifier.

This is **not** a problem for the class declarations (they should indeed be declared in shared header files). This is not a problem neither for the function member definitions, since as they are placed inside the `class` block, are implicitly `inline`.

It happens this is not a problem neither with `GPIN`, `RPIN` and `BPIN` variables. As they are declared `const` at global scope, they are implicitly `static`, meaning there is one distinct copy per compilation unit (usually compiled out by the optimizer however).

But `RGBLed Animation::myLED(RPIN, GPIN, BPIN, RGBLed::COMMON_CATHODE);` is a *definition*, which must be defined *once* to follow the [One Definition Rule (ODF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4192170).

So move most of your code into `Animation.h`, and `#include "Animation.h"` into both `main.cpp` and `Animation.cpp`. The definition of `Animation::myLED` must be in `Animation.cpp` and not in header. Also, I suggest to move the code marked `// do some magic` out of the `class` declaration into the implementation `.cpp` file. Better reserve `inline` methods to small functions like getters and setters. Also, prefer `constexpr` to declare constant values instead of old `const`.

Comment: Wow, this comment shows me how little i know about C++. Thank you for the detailed answer, I really appreciate people explaining things thoroughly as not only do I want to solve the problem but also to understand it. Thanks man